# jquery has no method error

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, href, addclass

I am  writing an ajax navigation script.
I found out i could highlight the current section into the menu by using

```
('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('current');
```

But I am getting this Error:

```
Object a[href="#home"] has no method 'addClass'
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something's missing:

```
$('a[href="' + document.location.hash + '"]').addClass('current');
```

Comment: thanks it worked fine; mixing up javascript, php and html tags into a line of code is insanely confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `$` sign?

Try:

```
$('a[href=' + document.location.hash + ']').addClass('current');
```

Without the `$`, the JavaScript parser will think it is a string object.